# Scraping data from URLs: how to retrieve all the URL pages with missing and unknown final page IDs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I wanted to pull down the data for a set of webpages.

This is an example of the URL:

http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_mammalia&s=details&id=3&listname=

My question is:

1. The 'id=' number in the URL changes between different pages.
2. I want to loop through and retrieve all of the pages in the database.
3. There will be id's missing (e.g. maybe there will be a page with id=3 and id=6, but not id=4 and id=5).
4. I do not know what the final number of the IDs is (e.g. maybe the last page in the database is id=100000 or id=1000000000, I do not know).

I know the general two lines of code I need will be to make a list of numbers somehow, and then to loop through the numbers with this code to pull down the text of each page (parsing the text itself is another day's work):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
web_page = "http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_mammalia&s=details&id=" + id_name + "&listname="
page = urllib2.urlopen(web_page)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
```

Can anyone advise on the best way to say 'take all of the pages' to get around the issues I'm facing of missing pages and not know when the last page is?

Comment: so you want pages ? content on pages ?

Comment: Yes I was hoping to parse the content on each page to a tab-delimited format, but the first specific problem I'm having is as described above. But if it suits better, I can trying parsing the data on one of the pages into tab-delimited format, and then put up the code for that instead (and then my question is the same, how would I run that piece of code on multiple pages, where the IDs of the pages are not a complete sequence and I do not know what the final number in the sequence is).

Comment: I'm not familiar with all that protein stuff, but maybe you could retrieve all the links to the existing pages from http://www.signalpeptide.de/?m=listspdb ? Then you don't need to guess ids any more, just follow the links.

Comment: i guess you can iterate for each request like, you can use the while loop and increment the `id` in the url and call the soup function for each request (response) and put that in a try except block, i guess it'll work.

Comment: So I did think of try and except, I didn't think it was very pythonic but is this what people generally do, just pick a really big number, say 1,000,000, and try for i in range (0,100000000): try/except? (without specifically knowing if you're actually getting all the data or not?)

Comment: Using try/except won't work as the site is returning response code `200` even for urls that don't have any information. So you'll have to parse each url and check whether the warning message is visible [like it is here](http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_mammalia&s=details&id=33333333333&listname=). It will be tedious. Simplest solution would be what @BUZZY suggested.

Comment: yea i guess it's not a great approach, however you don't need to use range function you can just use a while loop and increment a variable, and try /except will work when you try to access an element in the response like and id tag or so.

Comment: checking warning message not a quite of a task right ? and yes the link provided gives some info about the entries but certainly there are some entries beyond that.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a difficult task, but a task that will take much longer time to run. It would be easier and faster to just use the list of urls.

Comment: Instead of guessing numbers why can't you just iterate over the links at http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?m=listspdb_mammalia and the go to each protein details.

Comment: So actually for this suggestion, @codeadict, will I not have the same problem? That I will be looping through pages without knowing when to stop, because I don't know when the 'start=X' in the link [link]http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php?sess=&m=listspdb_mammalia&start=50&orderby=id&sortdir=asc[link] ends (i.e. how many peptides there are?). Just to clarify, I guess I could do as described above and search maybe a million IDs and hope I catch them all, it just doesn't seem very pythonic, so I was wondering what more experienced programmers do.

Comment: No, because the page bottom says `1 - 50 (of 13094)` so you can basically check if the last record `50` in this case is the same as the number of records `13094` then you stop the iteration because there are no more pages. I will post my code solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the possible pages, you can do something like(My example is Python3):

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import html

ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 50

base_url = 'http://www.signalpeptide.de/index.php'
url_params = '?sess=&m=listspdb_mammalia&start={}&orderby=id&sortdir=asc'


def get_pages(total):
    pages = [i for i in range(ITEMS_PER_PAGE, total, ITEMS_PER_PAGE)]
    last = pages[-1]
    if last < total:
        pages.append(last + (total - last))
    return pages

def generate_links():
    start_url = base_url + url_params.format(ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
    page = urlopen(start_url).read()
    dom = html.fromstring(page)
    xpath = '//div[@class="content"]/table[1]//tr[1]/td[3]/text()'
    pagination_text = dom.xpath(xpath)[0]
    total = int(re.findall(r'of\s(\w+)', pagination_text)[0])
    print(f'Number of records to scrape: {total}')
    pages = get_pages(total)
    links = (base_url + url_params.format(i) for i in pages)
    return links
```

Basically what it does is fetch the first page and obtain the number of records, given that every page has 50 records, the *get_pages()* function can calculate the page numbers passed to the **start** parameter and generates all the pagination URLs, you need to fetch all those pages, iterate the table with each protein and go to the details page to obtain the information you require using BeautifulSoup or lxml with XPath. I tried getting all this pages concurrently using asyncio and the server was timing out :). Hope my functions help!